# Activeadmin: Filtering in index do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am learning about activeadmin. I want that a column in my "index do" of my site display only certain values rather all. For example in my site there is a column score. This column shows the following values

11
10
5
6
7

then I need to know what method to use in the next lines

```
index do
   column : score
end do
```

to show only the values greater then 8. I am trying

```
index do
   column : score > 8
end do
```

or

```
column :if => proc { :cvss_base_score > 8 } do
    :cvss_base_score
end
```

but this does not work

Comment: is score an array?